# How to integrate Youtube Iframe api in reactjs solution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube-iframe-api

In react, I am trying to create a component for custom youtube player, so that I can introduce a new player controls bar. Form youtube iframe API, it was mentioned to use following code to create a player instance,

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
```

But when I am trying to use this code on react component life-cycle methods (like componentDidUpdate) YT instance isn't found at all.

Any solution to this ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here is a YouTubeVideo React component I wrote for a project recently.

When the component mounts, it checks to see if the YouTube iFrame API has already been loaded.

- If so, then it calls the API to create a new YouTube Player object directly.
- If not, it first waits for the script to load asynchronously and then load the video.

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

import classes from 'styles/YouTubeVideo.module.css';

class YouTubeVideo extends React.PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    // On mount, check to see if the API script is already loaded

    if (!window.YT) { // If not, load the script asynchronously
      const tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';

      // onYouTubeIframeAPIReady will load the video after the script is loaded
      window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = this.loadVideo;

      const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    } else { // If script is already there, load the video directly
      this.loadVideo();
    }
  };

  loadVideo = () => {
    const { id } = this.props;

    // the Player object is created uniquely based on the id in props
    this.player = new window.YT.Player(`youtube-player-${id}`, {
      videoId: id,
      events: {
        onReady: this.onPlayerReady,
      },
    });
  };

  onPlayerReady = event => {
    event.target.playVideo();
  };

  render = () => {
    const { id } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <div id={`youtube-player-${id}`} className={classes.video} />
      </div>
    );
  };
}

export default YouTubeVideo;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to the solution above you could use [react-youtube](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-youtube).

#### Installtion:

`npm install react-youtube`

#### Usage:

```
import React from "react";
import YouTube from "react-youtube";

function App() {
  const onPlayerReady = (event) => {
    const player = event.target;
    player.pauseVideo();
  };

  const onPlayerStateChange = (event) => {
    const player = event.target;
    player.playVideo();
  };

  const options = {
    height: "390",
    width: "640",
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 1,
    },
  };

  return (
    <YouTube
      videoId="AaGK-fj-BAM"
      opts={options}
      onReady={onPlayerReady}
      onStateChange={onPlayerStateChange}
    />
  );
}

export default App;
```

The library also supports TypeScript, check out the second example in the [Readme](https://github.com/tjallingt/react-youtube#example) if that's what you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `react-lite-youtube-embed` [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lite-youtube-embed) for embedding the video, but you can use this same method for any other iframe:

From the YT API Iframe documentation: [Use Youtube API with existing `<iframe>`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Example_Video_Player_Constructors):

1. Set the `enablejsapi` parameter to `1`.
2. Wait for the iframe to be loaded after user plays the video, `onIframeAdded` will be triggered.
3. Call the `loadYtPlayer` as the `onIframeAdded` callback: the code in this section loads the IFrame Player API JavaScript code. We don’t make any server request unless the user asks for it, this way the page renders way faster. (Note that you can load it directly  in componentDidMount event in React in case you prefer it)
4. Setup the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` function that will execute as soon as the player API code downloads. This portion of the code defines a global variable, `player`, which refers to the video player we are embedding, and the function then constructs the video player object.
5. The API will call the `onPlayerStateChange` function when the player's state changes, which may indicate that the player is playing, paused, finished, and so forth.

This is how I created the YoutubePlayer React component:

```js
import LiteYouTubeEmbed from 'react-lite-youtube-embed'
import 'react-lite-youtube-embed/dist/LiteYouTubeEmbed.css'
import { useRef } from 'react'

let player: { getCurrentTime: () => any }
let loadYtIframeAPI: Promise<any>

const YoutubePlayer = ({
  videoId,
  title,
  thumbnail,
}: {
  title: string
  videoId: string
  thumbnail: any
}) => {
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLIFrameElement>(null)

  const loadYtPlayer = () => {
    if (!loadYtIframeAPI) {
      loadYtIframeAPI = new Promise((resolve) => {
        const tag = document.createElement('script')
        tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'
        const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]
        firstScriptTag.parentNode?.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag)
        ;(window as any).onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = () =>
          resolve((window as any).YT)
      })
    }

    if (videoRef?.current) {
      loadYtIframeAPI.then((YT: any) => {
        player = new YT.Player(videoRef.current, {
          events: {
            onReady: onPlayerReady,
            onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange,
          },
        })
      })
    }
  }

  const onPlayerReady = (event: any) => {
    console.log('onPlayerReady event', event)
  }

  const onPlayerStateChange = (newState: { data: number }) => {
    if (newState.data == 1) {
      console.log('Video Playing')
    } else if (newState.data == 0) {
      console.log('Video Finished')
    } else if (newState.data == 2) {
      console.log('Video Paused', Math.round(player.getCurrentTime()))
    }
  }

  if (videoId) {
    return (
      <div className="aspect-video">
        <LiteYouTubeEmbed
          ref={videoRef}
          wrapperClass="yt-lite rounded-md"
          id={videoId}
          title={title}
          thumbnail={thumbnail}
          params="enablejsapi=1"
          onIframeAdded={loadYtPlayer}
        />
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return null
  }
}

export default YoutubePlayer
```